# Triggered Trapezoid Modelica

Tags: boolean-logic, modelica, openmodelica, dymola, feature-engineering

I am using a Triggered Trapezoid block within Modelica Logical Blocks.
I  am using it on a variable in my model, to eliminate the peaks that occur to this variable, because this variable is triggered by a boolean named ON, and when this boolean is equal to 1 the first seconds the variable records Peaks as it figures in the figure.

[image: 1]

When I use the Triggered Trapezoid it gives me the wrong value for my variable.
here is an extract from my model where I used the Triggered trapzoid:

```
 model prog
  Real y;
  Boolean u;
protected
 discrete Real endValue "Value of y at time of recent edge";
 discrete Real rate "Current rising/falling rate";
  discrete Modelica.SIunits.Time T "Predicted time of output reaching endValue";
equation
amplitude = Var;
  u = ON;
  y = if time < T then endValue - (T - time) * rate else endValue;
 when {initial(), u, not u} then
    endValue =  if u then offset + amplitude else offset;
    rate = if u and rising > 0 then amplitude / rising else if not u and falling > 0 then -amplitude / falling else 0;
    T = if u and not rising > 0 or not u and not falling > 0 or not abs(amplitude) > 0 or initial() then time else time + (endValue - pre(y)) / rate;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          end when;
end prog;
```

Comment: Difficult to help without knowing the input and/or desired behavior. Probably other blocks would be simpler to apply for filtering, e.g. `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.FirstOrder` or `SecondOrder`?

Comment: the prob that i had is that when the boolean=1 the valves open and the mass flow rate through it peaks at that instant, opening the valve gradually will help the model stability.

Comment: It will be great if you could provide minimum  version of the code that is able to compile if it doesn't expose confidentiality.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the following Modelica code:

```
model Test
  Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.SlewRateLimiter slewRateLimiter(Td = 0.5)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-4, 30}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.BooleanPulse booleanPulse(period = 10)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-82, 30}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.BooleanToReal booleanToReal annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-44, 30}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(booleanToReal.u, booleanPulse.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-56, 30}, {-70, 30}}, color = {255, 0, 255}));
  connect(booleanToReal.y, slewRateLimiter.u) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-32, 30}, {-16, 30}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end Test;
```

The above code produces the following output for a Boolean pulse (`Modelica.Blocks.Sources.BooleanPulse`) input:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

my goal was to turn a boolean to real for the purpose of gradually opening the valves within my model, the fault in my triggered trapezoid model is that I put amplitude= Var, and the Var was the mass flow rate of my valve. The correct thing is to put amplitude=ON, where ON is the boolean that controls the opening of the valve, after that I multiply the mass flow rate with "y" (the result of the triggered trapezoid block) and that will simulate the gradually opening of the valve

Comment: For what you want to achieve, I would have used a combination of a `Modelica.Blocks.Math.BooleanToReal` and a `Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.SlewRateLimiter` (at the output of the `BooleanToReal`).

Comment: Just as a note: It would make more sense to edit the original question than adding an answer to clarify the question.

Comment: @MarkusA.'s suggestion of using `Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.SlewRateLimiter` worked for me in one of my previous work so I will surely recommend trying that!